# PHP 5.4 code update - Creating default object from empty value warnings in foreach and objects array

Tags: php, warnings, strict

I have following code:

```
foreach($foo as $n=>$ia) {
    foreach($ia as $i=>$v) {
    $bar[$i]->$n = $v; //here I have 'Creating default object...' warning
    }
}
```

If I add:

```
$bar[$i] = new stdClass;
$bar[$i]->$n = $v;
```

to fix it. Then values in objects in array 'bar' not sets. For example, I have array:

```
 $foo = array(
 "somefield" => array("value1", "value2", "value3"),
 "anotherfield" => array("value1", "value2", "value3")
 );
```

On output I should get:

```
$bar[0]->somefield = value1
$bar[1]->anotherfield = value2
```

But in practice I get:

```
$bar[0]->somefield = null //(not set)
$bar[1]->anotherfield = null //too
```

How should I update the code to get it work?

Comment: For the life of me I cannot understand what this code is supposed to do and what the logic behind the desired output is. If it's so dense it definitely could use a rewrite.

Comment: Please use brackets to wrap the foreach statements!

Comment: As @MartinSamson says, the lack of brackets in the code given is disturbing, but the way you've written the question, with the 'if I add...' bit makes it hard to see what your code actually looks like - Please update the question to show the actual code that you have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Problem:**

The problem with your code is, that if you use the first attempt,

```
$bar[$i]->$n = $v;
```

a default empty object will be created for if you use the `->` operator on a non existent array index. (NULL). You'll get a warning as this is a bad coding practice.

The second attempt

```
$bar[$i] = new stdClass;
$bar[$i]->$n = $v;
```

will simply fail as you overwrite `$bar[$i]` each loop.

Btw the code above won't work even with PHP5.3

---

**Solution:**

I would prefer the following code example because:

- it works without warnings :)
- it don't uses the inline initialization features like in your question. I think its is good coding practice to declare `$bar` explicitely as empty `array()` and to create the objects using: `new StdClass()`.
- it uses descriptive variable names help to understand what the code is doing.

*code:*

```
<?php

$foo = array(
  "somefield" => array("value1", "value2", "value3"),
  "anotherfield" => array("value1", "value2", "value3")
);

// create the $bar explicitely
$bar = array();

// use '{ }' to enclose foreach loops. Use descriptive var names
foreach($foo as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $index => $value) {
        // if the object has not already created in previous loop
        // then create it. Note, that you overwrote the object with a 
        // new one each loop. Therefore it only contained 'anotherfield'
        if(!isset($bar[$index])) {
            $bar[$index] = new StdClass();
        }
        $bar[$index]->$key = $value;
    }
}

var_dump($bar);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked like a charm. Sorry for my ugly written example, yours really much better.

Comment: no problem! If you want to hear my opinion.. I think omitting `{}` in short `if`, `for`, `foreach`,... brings you nothing then trouble. I would spent that additional 2 seconds to place them. In any case. I makes your code more proof against logic errors and more readable. Also I would explicitely declare every variable that I use. Good luck! ;)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$bar = array();
foreach($foo as $n=>$ia)
   foreach($ia as $i=>$v)
      $bar[] = (object) array($n => $v);
```

this should give you:

```
$bar[0]->somefield = value1
$bar[1]->somefield = value2
$bar[2]->somefield = value3
$bar[3]->anotherfield = value1
$bar[4]->anotherfield = value2
$bar[5]->anotherfield = value3
```